# Exclude parent Category path from subcategory urls - Magento 1.13.1.0

Tags: magento-enterprise

I was using Magento 1.12.0.2 and recently upgraded to Magento 1.13.1.0.

My Site urls were www.abc.com/category/, www.abc.com/subcategory/ , www.abc.com/product.html
After upgrade the urls for products are working fine but category urls are adding . automatically before the "/" , so as per the new URL structure i remove the suffix / from the magento admin configuration and its working fine now . 
I also run  the URL migration  script but i still get he sub category url with parent category url included in URL like www.abc.com/category/subcategory

I check with core_url_rewrite table where the request_path is showing correct for all subcategory URLs where as in the newer version enterprise_url_reqrite ,subcategory urls are showing the request path as categoty/subcategory.

Is there any settings or code changes that can help me to fix the subcategory URLs that include only subcategory path and not include parent category path ? I also need "/" at the end to match my current URL structure. When i add "/" as a category url suffix in admin ,Magento 1.13.1.0 add "./" as a suffix for all category urls which leads to 404 page.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.13 there is an option to use categories path for product urls but there is no option to remove categories paths from category urls

So, i've created a simple module to workaround this.

https://github.com/alitopaloglu/ExcParentCatPathFromSubCatUrls

ATTENTION - DEVELOPED FOR ONLY MAGENTO ENTERPRISE EDITION v1.13

This module adds a yes/no option labelled as "Use Parent Category Path for Category URLs" on

Magento Admin Panel -> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Seo Options

to remove parent category path from url and change it from www.domain.com/cat1/cat2 to www.domain.com/cat2

USAGE :

Go to the Magento Admin Panel -> System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Seo Options
Select yes or no from "Use Parent Category Path for Category URLs"
Refresh category url index
Option YES => www.domain.com/cat1/cat2

Option NO => www.domain.com/cat2

Comment: Wow , Its working fine Thanks. Thanks Ali

Comment: Thanks - although the solution might be a little brittle related to upgrades - esp because this is so close to the core